# Creating an email address distribution list

Tags: email, google-workspace, distribution-list

In Exchange, I can create a distribution list and give that distribution list a specific email address. For instance, I have a domain - rodey.com and want to create a distribution list called "Drinking Buddies" and I want it to have the email address drinking.buddies@rodey.com. From there, I can add email addresses to my distribution group. To use, I send an email to drinking.buddies@rodey.com and then it is "forwarded" to the rest of the members?

I don't have a personal Exchange server so, how do I accomplish this otherwise? I do have a domain that is set up with Google Apps if that helps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To do this in Google Apps, you want to set up a [Group](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33329). Click on 'Manage This Domain' at the top of your email screen.  Then click on the 'Users and Groups' tab, and then the 'Groups' sub-tab, and then click 'Create a new group'.

I believe that should be what you are looking for.

Comment: That was perfect!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by creating a GROUP (Users and Groups / Groups tab, Create a new Group).  Just add all the emails in the Add New Members text area....and voila !!!

HEADS UP!  I have a over 15 group lists.... Some of my users are telling me that they are NOT receiving the email.  I have emailed google on this and havent yet receive an answer!  I even got my users to check in their junk/spam folder.

Good luck !